# Extension Layout won't work when using a custom theme

Tags: magento2, module, layout, blocks, theme

I have built an extension intending it to add a block underneath the Add to Cart button on the catalog product page.

My extension layout file isn't being executed - instead it just executes my custom theme layout only.

**Extension Layout** `vendor/extension/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="3columns" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="product.info.extrahint">
            <block
                    class="PHPete\ProductPage\Block\Product"
                    name="product.info.customblock"
                    template="PHPete_ProductPage::catalog/product/view/custom_block.phtml"
                    before="-"
            >
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Snippet of `design/frontend/vendor/CustomTheme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml`**

```
    <head>
        <css src="mage/gallery/gallery.css"/>
        <css src="mage/gallery/test.css"/>
    </head>
    <update handle="catalog_product_opengraph" />
    <update handle="page_calendar"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <container name="product.info.main" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-info-main" before="-">
                <container name="product.info.price" label="Product info auxiliary container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-info-price">
                    <container name="product.info.extrahint" as="extrahint" label="Product View Extra Hint">
                        <container name="product.info.social" label="Product social links container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-social-links">
                            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.addto" as="addto" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/addto.phtml">
                                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\AddTo\Compare" name="view.addto.compare" after="view.addto.wishlist"  template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/addto/compare.phtml" >
                                    <arguments>
                                        <argument name="addToCompareViewModel" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\ViewModel\Product\Checker\AddToCompareAvailability</argument>
                                    </arguments>
                                </block>
                            </block>
                            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.mailto" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/mailto.phtml"/>
                        </container>
                    </container>
                </container>
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

My `theme.type` is set to 0 (physical **not** virtual or staging)

If I switch back to Luma then it works perfectly.

Any advice would be great!

Pete

Comment: Generally, `/app/code/PHPete/ProductPage/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml` should be ok the way it is. However, in `design/frontend/vendor/CustomTheme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml` you basically redefine a huge portion of the product view. You probably want `<body><referenceContainer name="product.info.extrahint">...</referenceContainer></body>`. Not sure exactly what you are adding here, but, if you deal with already existing containers/blocks and want to add something inside/before/after you should do it as `reference`.

Comment: i.e. https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html#ref_container

Comment: Thanks Chris. I have used a Udemy course and the tutorial required me to copy that entire file, then make some changes. I'll try your suggestion and let you know what happens next.

Comment: Really all I'm building is a basic HTML module where I can pass strings & arrays accross to the template file. Just so I know how to add content before/inside/after for 'real-life' builds

Comment: Not sure what you mean to say, currently, simplified, what happens is the following: You've defined a layout update in your module; AFTERWARDS your theme's layout update comes in and basically overrides the whole `product.info.main` section, unsetting anything that would be added in there from any module.